# NoSuchMethodError when call pa.hdfs.connect

Tags: python, pyarrow

I'm using pyarrow to upload file to hdfs.But there is an error occured when call `pa.hdfs.connect`:

```
hdfsBuilderConnect(forceNewInstance=1, nn='host_nn', port=8020, kerbTicketCachePath=(NULL), userName=hdfs) error:
NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.AbstractMultimap: method <init>()V not foundjava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.AbstractMultimap: method <init>()V not found
    at com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap.<init>(LinkedListMultimap.java:199)
    at com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap.create(LinkedListMultimap.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.PeerCache.<init>(PeerCache.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ClientContext.<init>(ClientContext.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ClientContext.get(ClientContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getUnique(FileSystem.java:3311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.newInstance(FileSystem.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$2.run(FileSystem.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$2.run(FileSystem.java:496)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.newInstance(FileSystem.java:496)
```

My hdfs was *cdh 6.2*,and I had set java_home on my env which is jdk 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

[The Arrow JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20ARROW%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20component%20%3D%20Python%20AND%20text%20~%20hdfs%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC%2C%20priority%20DESC) shows a number of open HDFS issues: do any of these sound like yours?

If not, among the additional details you'd want to include when making a bug report there are the version of `pyarrow` you're using, whether you installed it with `conda` or `pip`, which version of libhdfs you have, as well as platform/OS information.